# Intuition of contour integration of |z|

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given the following contour integral:
$$ I=\int\limits_{-1}^1 |z| \ \mathrm{dz}, $$
with path of integration being the upper half of unit circle, it can be parameterized to give:
$$ \int\limits_{-1}^1 |z| \ \mathrm{dz} = -\int\limits_\Gamma |z| \ \mathrm{dz}, $$
where $\Gamma = e^{it}, \ t\in[0,\pi]$ and $\mathrm{dz}=ie^{it}\ \mathrm{dt},$ so
$$ -\int\limits_\Gamma |z| \ \mathrm{dz} = -\int\limits_0^\pi |e^{it}|\ ie^{it} \ \mathrm{dt}
= -i\int\limits_0^\pi e^{it} \ \mathrm{dt} = -i\left[ -ie^{it} \right]_0^\pi = -i^2-i^2 = 2. $$
Since $f:\Gamma \to \mathbb{R} \ $ given by $f(z)=|z|$ is a real-valued function of a complex variable, it can be visualized in 3D. And interpreting integral as "area under curve" it would seem natural to assume that $I=\pi\ $ which is incorrect.

The question is: what's wrong with this intuition and what's the correct way to think about the geometry of these types of integrals?

Comment: Contour integrals aren't areas under curves.  They are areas of "curtains" where the bottom of the curtain is traced out by the contour.  In this interpretation, I don't see why $I=\pi$ should be natural.

Comment: I don't know about "these types of integrals", but in this case, I think of it as just $\int_{-1}^1 dz$, and the imaginary component "cancels out" (so to speak), leaving just $2$.

Comment: You’re maybe intuitively and geometrically confusing the absolute value with the modulus. Another point: contour integrals are *integrals along the contour line* **not** integrals of areas below contour lines

Comment: @Randall The length of the contour is $\pi$ and the height at all points along it is $1,$ so under your interpretation the expected answer would still be $\pi.$

Comment: A better visualization is thinking of dz as a tiny vector, and adding those up

Comment: @StephenDonovan great (and fair) point.

Comment: I agree with eyeballfrog: contour integrals are closely related to line integrals in vector analysis. In a Riemann-style definition of the contour integral, the $dz$ in the integral can be seen as coming from the differences of points along the contour. As complex numbers, these differences have "direction," and add the way that vectors do. So basically the reason that integrating $|z| = 1$ over a contour of length $\pi$ doesn't give us $\pi$ is because not all of the $1$'s are in the same "direction."

Comment: Thank you to everyone who participated. It's all clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contour integrals in complex anaylsis are not areas under a curve. Instead, contour integrals rely on the interpretation of integrals as continuous weighted sums of differences. In the reals, an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx$ is the continuous version of a sum of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k)\Delta x_k$, where $\Delta x_k:=x_{k+1}-x_k$. Basically, we add up differences in $x$, but they are weighted with $f(x)$. When working in the reals, this happens to correspond to an area ($f(x_k)\Delta x_k$ is the area of a rectangle). But if we move on to complex numbers (and replace $x$ by $z$), neither $f(z_k)$, nor $\Delta z_k$ are real, except in the special case where we integrate along a horizontal line and $f$ is real on that line. In your case, $f$ happens to be real on the contour, but the differences $\Delta z_k$ along the contour are not. So the weighted sum which becomes the integral in the limit where $\Delta z_k\to0$ is not real, and thus not an area.

To get an area under the curve we would have to consider sums of the form $\sum \vert z\vert \vert\Delta z_k\vert$ instead.